# Cannot start npm

Tags: node.js, angular, gulp

I installed the seed app here: https://github.com/moizKachwala/Angular2-expressjs-mongoose-gulp-node-typescript
 I'm trying to run npm start but the server is not being created and started.

I thought maybe this line "(node:16596) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version" was the issue and I found that on SO its was suggested to make sure you have latest npm which I do.

NOTE: The gulp script is supposed to create the  dist folder where it will place all the js files but the dist folder is not being created so the gulp script is failing somewhere...

What else could it be?

```
c:\work\angular\pricecompare1>npm start

> angular2-express@1.0.0 start c:\work\angular\pricecompare1
> concurrent --kill-others "gulp watch" "gulp start"

[1] [09:35:54]
[0] [09:35:54] Requiring external module ts-node/register
[1] Requiring external module ts-node/register
[0] (node:16596) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
[1] (node:17124) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
[0] [09:35:55]
[0] Using gulpfile c:\work\angular\pricecompare1\gulpfile.ts
[1] [09:35:55] Using gulpfile c:\work\angular\pricecompare1\gulpfile.ts
[0] [09:35:55]
[0] Starting 'watch'...
[1] [09:35:55]
[1] Starting 'start'...
[1] [09:35:55]
[1] Finished 'start' after 1.88 ms
[1] [09:35:55] [nodemon] 1.10.0
[1] [09:35:55] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[1] [09:35:55] [nodemon] watching: *.*
[1] [09:35:55] [nodemon] starting `node dist/server/server.js`
[0] [09:35:55] Finished 'watch' after 32 ms
[1] module.js:442
[1]     throw err;
[1]     ^
[1]
[1] Error: Cannot find module 'c:\work\angular\pricecompare1\dist\server\server.js'
[1]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
[1]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
[1]     at Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
[1]     at run (bootstrap_node.js:352:7)
[1]     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:144:9)
[1]     at bootstrap_node.js:467:3
[1] [09:35:55] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: It looks like the error was thrown because it couldn't find your server.js. I would make sure that the file is mapped right.

Answer (score 0):

in your package.json file find start command and reference your server.js with correct directory

```
pricecompare1\dist\server\server.js
```

Comment: The gulp script is supposed to create the  dist folder where it will place all the js files